# dns hierarchy not returning ip address

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, query, authoritative

```
(DNS1 ,WWW1, Gateway1) (sub-internal network)   
(DNS0,WWW0,Gateway0) (internal network)

DNS1: 192.168.250.3/24   
WWW1: 192.168.250.4/24  
Gateway1: 192.168.250.1 /24 (internal)   ::  192.168.0.150 to 192.168.0.175 (external)


DNS0:192.168.0.197/24  
WWW0:192.168.0.197/24  
Gateway0: 192.168.0.1 (internal) :: 69.94.x.x (external, dynamic ,isp control)
```

Expected behavior: When using dig from internal (192.168.250.0/24) hosts, and query about domain from 192.168.0.197/16 nameserver's hosts (for which its authoritative), it should return the ip address.

What's happening: After dig, answer section empty, the query is trying to access a.root server instead of 192.168.0.197 ,even though I have defined 192.168.0.197 as dns in gateway1's resolv.conf

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 2 DNS servers in this setup?
You can just use one, serving DNS requests for your whole network.
Clients on other subnets just need to have access to this DNS server via a default gateway into the network where the DNS server is located.

Comment: Because I want to establish a hierarchy as in real world, and 192.168.250.0/24 can have internal changes without 192.168.0.0/16 knowing about it. Also, 192.168.0.0 should be able to access 192.168.250.0/24 by "domain names" and the vice versa should be possible using same method.